# Is that Spring transaction is applied to normal(non DB) operations as well?

Tags: java, spring-transactions

I have applied spring transaction on service layer of application. There is one method which performing following two operations 
 
1) send message to SQS. 
2) And logs that entry in DB. 
So, while adding log in DB if any exception occurs then operation (1) will roll backed ? OR Spring will apply transaction on non DB operations ?

Answer (score 1):

Rollback in case of exception is applied to anything that is managed by that transaction. Sending a message to the SQS is not managed by the database transaction, therefore it will not be rolledback.

To achieve this you would need to make a hook into the rollback and do the rollback equivalent of the sending the message to SQS.

Comment: thanks for reply. Could you explain in detail how can we apply rollback for operation (1) ?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with SQS but my educated guess would be that you'd just delete the message. However, one would need to consider the scenario where the message has been already picked up by some other consumer to be consumed from the queue. So I'd recommend, you write to database, commit transaction. If that all works then send message to sqs.